# Is there a fast way to do check in lock on pending changes in TFS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I know we can go to solutions explorer and select files to do check in lock, but this is slow. Is there any extension or option to just do check in lock on all the files with pending changes?

Comment: What's the detail mean of `lock on pending changes` are you talking about? Did you just want to check in other's locked files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are talking about is check-in lock.   For example:

Developer A has checked out `$/FabrikamTFVC/Main/Source/FabrikamFiber.CallCenter/FabrikamFiber.Web/Web.config` in the FabrikamTFVC project with a check-in lock type. So while other users can check out the `Web.config` file, no one can check in Web.config until developer **A** has lifted this lock:

[image]

In the following image, `Web.config` is checked out with the check-in **lock**. This is represented by lock in the **Pending Change** column:

[image]

You could download **TFS Power Tools** and you can see **Find by Status** under
 Find in the Source Control Explorer. Then follow the below steps -

> 1. From the Source Control Explorer find the folder containing the
>      locked file(s).
> 2. Right-click and select **Find** then **Find by Status**...
> 3. The "Find in Source Control" window appears
> 4. Click the **Find** button
> 5. A "Find in Source Control" tab should appear showing the file(s)
>      that are checked out
> 6. Right click the file you want to unlock
> 7. Select **Undo**... from the context menu
> 8. A confirmation dialog appears. Click the **Yes** button.
> 9. The file should disappear from the "Find in Source Control" window.
>
> *[Source Link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/149799/file-locked-by-other-user-in-tfs-2017-need-to-unlo.html)*

Or you could try to use [Lock command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/lock-command?view=vsts) to remove other users lock for an item. Eg: `c:\projects>tf lock /lock:none src/`

---

**Update:**

You could also create your own customize check in policy to met your requirement. Check-in policy **enforces constraints every time** when files are checked into TFS source control. The user must meet the policy restriction, then could check in files.

How to please refer this blog: [**Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy**](https://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)

Comment: Hi Patrick! Thanks for the answer. My problem is a little different. We have a big team of developers working on relatively small number of files. So the team keeps checking in same files concurrently and sometimes they mess up with merging to latest changes and the other times TFS itself messes up the auto merge. So I want a developer to check in lock the files with pending changes just before he is about to check in and merge all his changes properly and then release the check in lock after he checkin's all the files.

Comment: @Nitheesh In this case, you could consider use custom check in policy, for example take a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899859/tfs-set-a-branch-to-allow-check-ins-of-merge-changeset-only . If this not totally met your requirement, you could also create your own customize check in policy. How to please refer this blog: https://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html

Comment: We haven't implemented it yet, we have added a backlog item for this and we will work on this soon. The post you suggested " blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html" I think is the way to go. We will use that as a starting point. If you can add it as a answer I will accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nitheesh Have done. Appreciate for your kindly remind.